# What is the most time-efficient way to earn gold in Barbarian Prince?

Tags: statistics, barbarian-prince

Like the title says. Does this change over the course of the game (example, when you hire followers, when a wizard/witch/monk join your party)?

What is the average gold earned per day using the most efficient strategy?